# Como fazer postagem no facebook com java RestFB?

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação `JavaSE` para fazer postagens no facebook, mas não sei por onde começar, estava vendo exemplos, mas só achei sobre `JSP`.

Como eu faço o login para obter o token do Facebook? Eu pensei em abrir um "navegador" interno e enviar no link pra me retornar ao token, mas como eu vou recuperar esse token?

Não sei se preciso fazer isso, pois não sei se o [RestFB](http://restfb.com/) já tem algo para isso.

Alguém me da uma luz com um exemplo explicado com `JavaSE` por favor.

Comment: O que você tentou até agora para fazer o login e obter o *token*? Está com problema em obter o *token* ou alguma problema específico no uso do `RestFB`?

Comment: Problema com obter o token